# Resizing UICollectionView with Custom Layout after adding or deleting cells in swift using Pinterest cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, pinterest

I downloaded follow Pintrest Custom Layout for my CollectionView from : 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

So the layout works fine, i got it set up so when you scroll to the bottom, I need to make it implement like pagination functionality.

**Problem:** If a user add or delete data from array then cells is not reflecting for their layout. For example: if I have 35 objects in array for first time and I have deleted 5 record then scrollable should be fixed to 32 objects while it is showing till 35 objects but record is displaying correctly in the case of delete. But if we add next 35 objects at runtime, then my array is having 70 records, but collection view not reloading data it still displaying 35 records.

How can i remove this space white space in the case of delete? 
and How can I reload it and show more cell in case of adding?

Please help.

Comment: try to use `collectionView.collectionViewLayout?.invalidate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found my answer.

just comment the given below code written in prepare function

```
guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView
else {
        return
    }
```

and just after commented the above code, write the given below code:

```
cache.removeAll()
guard cache.isEmpty == true || cache.isEmpty == false, let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }
    contentHeight = 0
```

in the same function. it is working now finally.

Comment: Thanks got the idea!!, but don't understand why you checked both the empty and not empty condition for cache. It does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

In the case above `cache.isEmpty == true || cache.isEmpty == false`, you do not actually check anything about the cached elements. The code is as same as `guard let collectionView = collectionView else {return}`

This is not a proper way to prepare layouts. If you add new items to the cache, you should not recalculate the existing elements. It is not only an unnecessary operation but also bad user experience. While the user scrolls down, the cells will change immediately for the existing items.

To properly handle appending new elements, you can do this;
`guard cache.isEmpty || collectionViewItemCount > cache.count, let collectionView = collectionView else { return }`

```
override func prepare() {
    let collectionViewItemCount = delegate?.numberOfItemsInCollectionView() ?? 0
    guard cache.isEmpty || collectionViewItemCount > cache.count, let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
    
    .
    .
    .
    
    // set the last cached item's height to the yOffSet 
    for index in 0..<yOffset.count {
        yOffset[index % numberOfColumns] = cache.last(where: {$0.indexPath.row % numberOfColumns == index % numberOfColumns})?.frame.maxY ?? 0
    }
    
    for item in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
        if indexPath.row >= cache.count {
    .
    .
    .
     cache.append(attributes)
    .
    .
    .        
        }
    }
}
```

p.s.: you also need to add `func numberOfItemsInCollectionView() -> Int` to the PinterestLayoutDelegate